# Horizontal scroll using Polymer

Tags: polymer

[image]
The section in the image that says `People also search for`, there is a horizontal list of items which is scrollable. I've to do the same thing using polymer, but can't find anything similar to it. I've already implemented vertical lists, but not sure about the horizontal ones.
Another question is that would it possible to use a viewpager like component for this kind of scenario? Paper-Tabs do provi this functionality, however swipe gesture does not work on it. Pages change only if we click a tab.

Comment: Maybe you want to check out this code lab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-2-carousel/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fpolymer-summit-2016&viewga=UA-39334307-12#8 - it shows hot to implement a swipeable image carousel with Polymer (2.0) and could help you find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The scrollable suggestion box in Google search is a simple box with horizontal scroll overflow (and not paginated like in a tab view). The scrolling part of that suggestion box could be easily implemented with two nested `div` containers, with the outer `div` styled with `overflow-x: auto` and the inner `div` styled with `white-space: nowrap`, as shown in this example:

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto">
  <div style="white-space: nowrap">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[suggestions]]">
      ...
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

[`overflow-x: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) tells the browser to render a scrollbar and clip the overflow content when it overflows at the edges.

[`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) disables wrapping of elements when line overflow occurs so that the elements remain on the same line.

```js
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', () => {
  class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }

    static get properties() {
      return {
        suggestions: {
          value: () => [
            {title: 'polymer gestures', url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=polymer+gestures'},
            {title: 'polymer elements', url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=polymer+elements'}
          ]
        }
      };
    }
  }
  customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);

  customElements.define('x-suggestions', class extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'x-suggestions' }

    static get properties() {
      return {
        suggestions: Array
      };
    }

    _onClickFeedback() {
      console.log('feedback');
    }

    _onClickClose() {
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close', {detail: {el: this}}));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.3.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        x-suggestions {
          width: 350px;
        }
      </style>
      <x-suggestions suggestions="[[suggestions]]"></x-suggestions>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="x-suggestions">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
          background: #f8f8f8;
          color: #6a6a6a;
          padding-bottom: 1rem;
        }
        .title {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1.3rem;
        }
        .feedback {
          text-decoration: none;
          font-style: italic;
          color: #6a6a6a;
          margin: 1rem;
        }
        .suggestion {
          text-decoration: none;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: black;
        }
        .suggestions-outer {
          overflow-x: auto;
        }
        .suggestions-inner {
          white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .suggestion-box {
          display: inline-flex;
          margin: 0.2rem;
          padding: 1em 1em 1em 0.5em;
          border: solid 1px #ddd;
          border-radius: 2px;
        }
        .header {
          display: flex;
          border-top: solid 2px #e9e9e9;
        }
        .close-btn {
          background: transparent;
          border: none;
          margin: 10px 10px 10px auto;
          font-size: 1rem;
          color: #6a6a6a;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .icon-search {
          color: #717171;
          --iron-icon-height: 28px;
          --iron-icon-width: 28px;
        }
      </style>

      <header class="header">
        <h3 class="title">People also search for</h3>
        <button class="close-btn" title$="Close" on-click="_onClickClose">✕</button>
      </header>

      <div class="suggestions-outer">
        <div class="suggestions-inner">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[suggestions]]">
            <div class="suggestion-box">
              <a class="suggestion" target$="_blank" href$="[[item.url]]">
                <iron-icon class="icon-search" icon="search"></iron-icon>
                <span>[[item.title]]</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </template>
          <a href="#" class="feedback" on-click="_onClickFeedback">Feedback</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gozzvG?editors=1010)